# Google Calendar API: Class "Google\Service" not found

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I try to update my PHP application to the latest Google API (I have upgrated to PHP 8.0 and my previous (very old!) version of the Google API does not work with PHP 8.0).

I have downloaded *google-api-php-client--PHP8.0.zip* and *google-api-php-client-services-main.zip* and copied all files in the src folder from *google-api-php-client--PHP8.0.zip* to /src/Google/....

[image]

... and from *google-api-php-client-services-main.zip* the Calendar.php file and the Calendar folder also to /src/Google/....

In my php file I run the following statements at the very beginning:

```
require_once './src/Google/autoload.php';
require_once "./src/Google/Client.php";
require_once "./src/Google/Calendar.php";
```

However, I get the following error:
*Class "Google\Service" not found in /src/Google/Calendar.php:35*

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Try using Composer instead of downloading and requiring resources by yourself.

Comment: I am not working in the Google environment, my website which needs this functionality is on a different hosting service. I wonder what has changed compared to the old version - because with the old version it worked like a charm.

Comment: I wonder if my directory tree is correct. I set up it in the same way I had it for the old version, but something might have changed.

Comment: The class `Google\Service` is missing. Maybe in the old version it wasn't used. You can try to require the corresponding file, but it can be not the only one missing resource. The best way to ensure your app will load all from that library is using Composer. As you are updating your PHP application, is a good time to incorporate Composer.